# not able to link SurfaceViewExample to MainActivity

Tags: android

In DrawingTheBall class making some animation stuff..
In SUrfaceViewExample class Touchevent will be detecetd..
my problem is i am not able to link MainActivity and SurtfaceViewExample ..
no issues with DrawingTheBall..
MAIN CLASS:...

```
package maddy.first;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Madhu1Activity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Drwwingtheball v;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            v = new Drawingtheball(this);
            setContentView(v);
        } 
}
```

CLASS SurfaceViewExample:

```
package maddy.first;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

  OurView v;
  Bitmap ball;
  float x,y;
        @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            v=new OurView(this);
            v.setOnTouchListener(this);
     ball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tennis_ball);
           x = y = 0;
           setContentView(v);
      }
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
    }
public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    SurfaceHolder holder;

    boolean isItOk=false;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           holder=getHolder();
      }


public void run() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while( isItOk ==true)
    {
     //drawing   
     if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {

        continue;

     }

     Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
     c.drawARGB(255,150,150,10);    
     c.drawBitmap(ball, x-(ball.getWidth()), y-(ball.getHeight()), null);

     holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);     

    }
 }
public void pause()
{
    isItOk=false;
    while(true) {
        try {
            t.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        break;

    }
}

 public void resume()
 {
   isItOk=true;  
   t=new Thread(this);
   t.start();
 }

  }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return false;
     } 


 }
```

Class DrawingTheBall:

```
package maddy.first;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;
public class DrawingTheBall extends View { 

    Bitmap bball;
    int x,y;
public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
        super(context);

    bball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() ,R.drawable.tennis_ball);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        }
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {
super.onDraw(canvas);
    Rect ourRect=new Rect();
    ourRect.contains( 0, 0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);
    Paint blue=new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.RED);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);
    if(x < canvas.getWidth())
    x+=10;
    else
        x=0;
    if(y<canvas.getHeight())
    y+=10;
    else
         y=0;
    Paint p=new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bball,x,y,p);
    invalidate();
  }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What actually do you want to link?
You want to start activity from another another?
Or you want to pass some parameter from one to another activity?

If you want to run SurfaceViewExample activity from Main activity  - 
This is the code -

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SurfaceViewExample.class)
finish();
```

And AndroidManifest.xml file should be -

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="Madhu1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SurfaceViewExample"></activity>
</application>
```

And if you want to pass parameter from one activity to another - 
This is the code -

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SurfaceViewExample.class)
    .putExtra("key", [value])); // if you want to pass class the class should be Serializable, otherwise you can pass value like a hash map.

//in other activity convert it to class-
<classname> obj = (<classname>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
```

If this are not sufficient then tell me what actually want.

Enjoy..

Comment: i pasted : startActivity(new Intent(this, SurfaceViewExample.class)
finish(); in Main activity but it did not worked.I want Run specifically SurfaceViewExample class.please help me @Suvam Roy

Answer (score 0):

I think it throws some exception otherwise your layout has some error, so that it is unable to set the content view.
This is the easiest way to keep your SurfaceViewExample class as main activity follow it - 
goto application AndroidManifest.xml file and then -

```
Application tab -> select launch activity(that is your main activity) ->
Name*(right side) -> browse(take for a while to loading activity list) - > 
select SurfaceViewExample -> remove previous SurfaceViewExample activity if already added.
```

set a default layout in SurfaceViewExample setContentView(layout.main); // if it exists
And run your application to check it is able to show your layout. 
If it can run successfully, then check out your DrawingTheBall code.
Have fun...